# there is a method to change the value of a particular cell in a DataFrame keeping the difference in another array with the same column name and index

Tags: python, pandas, cell

[image]

having a dataframe with more rows and columns, I would love to replace the values that are larger than the mean of rows, with the value that is small or equal to the mean.
By changing this value I would like to keep the difference with the old value in another dataframe by keeping the same column name and row index.

as an example of the first row I would like to keep the values of 1000 and 2023 leave 1000 in the cell, and the remaining 2000 put them in a Data frame like this result.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

(Not sure what you want exactly given your post mentions "mean" but your example uses "min"...)

With numpy (I'll let you adapt to pandas if you need):

```
# define sample array
a = np.arange(24)
np.random.shuffle(a)
a = a.reshape((4,6))
a

# array([[13, 12, 11,  9, 20,  2],
#        [18,  8, 22,  7, 10,  5],
#        [ 6,  1, 23, 16,  3, 19],
#        [15, 14,  0,  4, 17, 21]])

# subtract minimum value from each row
a-a.min(axis=1, keepdims=True)

# array([[11, 10,  9,  7, 18,  0],
#        [13,  3, 17,  2,  5,  0],
#        [ 5,  0, 22, 15,  2, 18],
#        [15, 14,  0,  4, 17, 21]])
```

Comment: yes because if you compare the mean of each line you will find that we return to the min (just in this particular case that I gave), anyway I understood your method

Comment: It's helpful for me thank u